# How to use a trained model(.pb graph) in \image_retraining\retrain.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

So, I used the image_retraining\retrain.py from the tensorflow github which uses
inception model for transfer learning.

Now I have a `.pb` graph, which I would like as the model/architecture to use for training with the \image_retraining\retrain.py file, instead of the inception model.

Since this `.pb` was orginally trained on the inception model, I'm assuming it's not to difficult to use this graph as the model as well?

I know there is an architecture argument, which allows us to change the architecture to either "Inception" or "MobileNet" -- but don't know how to insert a .pb graph there.

Thank you.

Thanks.